# how to rename an index in a cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to rename several indexes in a cluster (their name **must** be changed, I cannot use [aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)).

I saw that there are no supported ways to do that, the closest I found is to [rename the directory of the index](https://gist.github.com/nz/6322673), I tried this in a cluster.

The cluster has 3 machines `A`, `B` and `C` and the shards are replicated on each of them. I shut down elasticsearch on `A`, renamed `/var/lib/elasticsearch/security/nodes/0/indices/oldindexname` to `/var/lib/elasticsearch/security/nodes/0/indices/newindexname` and restarted `A`.

The state of the cluster was yellow and elasticsearch was doing some magic to restore a correct state. After some time I ended up with

- `oldindexname` being available and fully replicated (recovered from `B` and `C` I guess)
- `newindexname` being available (I can search it) but the head plugin shows that its shards are in an "Unassigned" state and that they are grayed out (not replicated)

During the recovery `security.log` showed the following message:

```
[2015-02-20 11:02:33,461][INFO ][gateway.local.state.meta ] [A.example.com] dangled index directory name is [newindexname], state name is [oldindexname], renaming to directory name
```

While `newindexname` is searchable, it is certainly not in a normal state.

I rolled back to the previous state by deleting `newindexname`. The cluster is back to green without any "Unassigned" entries.

Given that, how can I rename `oldindexname` to `newindexname` in a cluster?

**Note:** the ultimate solution I have in mind is to scroll-copy `oldindex` into `newindex` and delete `oldindex` afterwards. This is going to take time so if there is a more direct solution it would be great.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Starting with ElasticSearch 7.4, the best method to rename an index is to copy the index using the newly introduced [Clone Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clone-index.html), then to delete the original index using the [Delete Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html).

The main advantage of the Clone Index API over the use of the Snapshot API or the Reindex API for the same purpose is speed, since the Clone Index API hardlinks segments from the source index to the target index, without reprocessing any of its content (on filesystems that support hardlinks, obviously; otherwise, files are copied at the file system level, which is still much more efficient that the alternatives). Clone Index also guarantee that the target index is identical in every point to the source index (that is, there is no need to manually copy settings and mappings, contrary to the Reindex approach), and doesn't require a local snapshot directory be configured.

***Side note:*** even though this procedure is much faster than previous solutions, it still implies down time. There are real use cases that justify renaming indices (for example, as a step in a split, shrink or backup workflow), but renaming indices should not be part of day-to-day operations. If your workflow requires frequent index renaming, then you should consider using [Indices Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) instead.

Here is an example of a complete sequence of operations to rename index `source_index` to `target_index`. It can be executed using some ElasticSearch specific console, such as the one integrated [in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mjameswh/59c1f59497c03a5cf3697eeb6ca2445d) for an alternative version of this example, using `curl` instead of an Elastic Search console.

```
# Make sure the source index is actually open
POST /source_index/_open

# Put the source index in read-only mode
PUT /source_index/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.blocks.write": "true"
  }
}

# Clone the source index to the target name, and set the target to read-write mode
POST /source_index/_clone/target_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.blocks.write": null 
  }
}

# Wait until the target index is green;
# it should usually be fast (assuming your filesystem supports hard links).
GET /_cluster/health/target_index?wait_for_status=green&timeout=30s

# If it appears to be taking too much time for the cluster to get back to green,
# the following requests might help you identify eventual outstanding issues (if any)
GET /_cat/indices/target_index
GET /_cat/recovery/target_index
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain

# Delete the source index
DELETE /source_index
```

Comment: In "Put the source index in read-only mode" you say `"index.blocks.write": "true"` which reads a bit like there should be `false` instead.. is that a typo or can you explain why `true` is correct here?

Comment: Ah nevermind, `blocks` as in `blocking`, got it

Comment: side note: for me it was  `PUT /settings {"index": {"blocks": {"write": false}}}` ..with the leading `"settings"` key it didnt gave an error, but the index was still read-only afterwards oO

Comment: This is really helpful specially step by steps on performing cloning. Almost similar steps applies to reindex.

Comment: I would like to note that cloning seems to re-set `index.number_of_replicas` to 1, so I also had to pass `index.number_of_replicas` with value I had before as POST payload.

Answer (score 210):

You can use [REINDEX](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to do that.

> Reindex does not attempt to set up the destination index. It does not
>   copy the settings of the source index. You should [set up the
>   destination index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/indices-create-index.html) prior to running a _reindex action, including
>   setting up mappings, shard counts, replicas, etc.

1. First copy the index to a new name

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```

2. Now delete the Index

```
DELETE /twitter
```

Comment: Does this work if the mapping has `_source: {enabled: false}`?

Comment: @Harald No, `_reindex` uses `_source` as the original document data.

Comment: This won't copy the mapping of `twitter` to `new_twitter` as far as I know.

Comment: Note that `REINDEX` is considered experimental in Elastic 5.1

Comment: @mthmulders Are you sure it's considered experimental in 5.1?  I see a note saying that it's experimental in 2.4, but nothing in any of the 5.x versions: [2.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-reindex.html) vs. [5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/docs-reindex.html)

Comment: @M.Justin Well, I'm pretty sure it had the "Experimental" mark when I posted that remark. But indeed, it's not there (anymore). So I suppose it can be used without precautions. Thanks for the check!

Comment: I agree on the solution of _reindex, but the question should be changed.
Reindexing is not simply a renaming. It can even change how data is indexed.

Comment: Reindexing can take a long time, so I highly recommend setting timeouts appropriately, as per the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: I'd also point out that `reindex` doesn't carry the previous index configuration, so you should properly set the new index with the old configuration before performing the operation (you can get that by making a request to `<addr>:9200/<index>/_settings,_mappings`. I followed the example of this answer and wrote about my experience at https://ops.tips/blog/change-name-of-index-elasticsearch (it's just me going through what has been answered here).

Comment: It gave me an 'index_not_found_exception' error when I did DELETE /twitter.

Answer (score 69):

For renaming your index you can use Elasticsearch Snapshot module.

First you have to take snapshot of your index.while restoring it you can 
rename your index.

```
    POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
    {
     "indices": "jal",
     "ignore_unavailable": "true",
     "include_global_state": false,
     "rename_pattern": "jal",
     "rename_replacement": "jal1"
     }
```

rename_replacement :-New indexname in which you want backup your data.

Comment: Much better than the accepted solution! This is actually a binary copy of the index, so no risk of losing anything and doesn't require `_source` to be enabled in the index. I have renamed some multi-TB indices this way without any issues.

Comment: does it retain the mapping?

Comment: @krishnakumar What is `my_backup` and `snapshot_1` here? I suppose, the current index name is `jal` and new index name is `jal1`.

Comment: @AmoghMishra - No you need to put mapping again.

Answer (score 10):

If you can't REINDEX a **workaround** is to use *aliases*. From the [official](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) documentation:

*APIs in elasticsearch accept an index name when working against a specific index, and several indices when applicable. The index aliases API allow to alias an index with a name, with all APIs automatically converting the alias name to the actual index name. An alias can also be mapped to more than one index, and when specifying it, the alias will automatically expand to the aliases indices. An alias can also be associated with a filter that will automatically be applied when searching, and routing values. An alias cannot have the same name as an index.*

Be aware that this solution does not work if you're using More Like This feature. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16560

Comment: `I need to rename several indexes in a cluster (their name must be changed I cannot use aliases).` By @WoJ

Comment: *Reason alias won't work*: Using `alias` _requires_ you to plan ahead and create the original index name `as an alias` to a real index.  Then you can create a new alias name and re-use the old alias name for something else.  *But* you lose access to old_data if you have only have a real_index, make an alias to it, delete the old real_index.  The alias now points to nothing.

Comment: @JesseChrisholm I think one cannot have an "alias that points to nothing". Try removing real_index, you'll see that the alias "an alias to it" will also be removed.

Answer (score 5):

As such there is no direct method to copy or rename index in ES (I did search extensively for my own project)

However a very easy option is to use a popular migration tool [Elastic-Exporter].

http://www.retailmenot.com/corp/eng/posts/2014/12/02/elasticsearch-cluster-migration/

[PS: this is not my blog, just stumbled upon and found it good]

Thereby you can copy index/type and then delete the old one.

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Any other place we could find it or have this info?

Answer (score 5):

Another different way to achieve the renaming or change the mappings for an index is to reindex using logstash.
Here is a sample of the logstash 2.1 configuration:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["es01.example.com", "es02.example.com"]
   index => "old-index-name"
   size => 500
   scroll => "5m"
  }
}
filter {

 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version" ]
 }

 date {
   "match" => [ "custom_timestamp", "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ]
   target => "@timestamp"
 }

}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["es01.example.com", "es02.example.com" ]
   manage_template => false
   index => "new-index-name"
 }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the best way to reindex an Elasticsearch index is to install Logstash, and then use that to reindex?  Seems a bit overkill, especially if you don't actually want/use Logstash...

Comment: The only problem in the answer is the "The best" part. I would say "Another way'. Other than that, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in [Elasticsearch reference for snapshot module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_restore),

> The rename_pattern and rename_replacement options can be also used to rename index on restore using regular expression

Answer (score 3):

For those landing here based on OpenSearch, here's how you do it...

`PUT /<source-index>/_block/write`

`DELETE <target-index>` (if one already exists)

`PUT /<source-index>/_clone/<target-index>`

Answer (score -12):

Just in case someone still needs it. The successful, not official, way to rename indexes are:

1. Close indexes that need to be renamed
2. Rename indexes' folders in all data directories of master and data nodes.
3. Reopen old closed indexes (I use kofp plugin). Old indexes will be reopened but stay unassigned. New indexes will appear in closed state
4. Reopen new indexes
5. Delete old indexes

If you happen to get this error "dangled index directory name is", remove index folder in all master nodes (not data nodes), and restart one of the data nodes.

Comment: Strongly discouraged by Elastic. Ensure to have backups if you do so.

Comment: I don't understand where the name of the index appears in the data directory. When I look in /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/ the names of the directories are random-generated, like "1aS4RusHSYWLdt-Wx7NnBw" (Elasticsearch version 5.6.3)

Comment: @JohanBoulé, this method is no longer valid since version 5 of Elasticsearch.

Comment: @lucabelluccini, agreed. Better to just leave them as is and use aliases.