# Is there a way to change the name of an Index in ElasticSearch after data has been loaded?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I create and bulk load a bunch of individual data records of type ***person*** (JSON formatted) into an ElasticSearch index called ***enterprise*** using a command like:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/enterprise/person/_bulk --data-binary  @./JSON_DATA/people1.json
```

Is there a simple way to change the name of the ***enterprise*** index to something like ***last_enterprise*** after it's already been loaded with data?  And, if so, does it trigger/force re-indexing or not (and why)?

Any help you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626803/how-to-rename-an-index-in-a-cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use aliases. Really easy to use and flexible.

My advice: always use aliases.