# How to rename index with reindex API

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I'm trying to rename an index on Elasticsearch and as suggested in the accepted solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626803/how-to-rename-an-index-in-a-cluster/34318213#34318213) I'm using the Reindex API. I'm using the following command:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "original-index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new-index"
  }
}
```

But I'm receiving this output:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "message": "Unable to connect to the server."
}
```

I have tried creating the index before doing the reindex and without having it created and every time I get the same output. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
I have just tested it again and it happens something strange. The index is being reindexed, but the error message is still being displayed. Any explanation about that? The message is confusing cause it seems to have failed, but it should be running still...**

Comment: Are you running the command in Kibana?

Comment: Can you verify your elasticsaerch server is running or not ?

Comment: Yes, I was running it in Kibana. @TheUknown

Comment: I verified it cause it responded to all my other petitions. It was only the reindex the one that was failing. @AshwaniShakya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EDIT: I have just tested it again and it happens something strange. The index is being reindexed, but the error message is still being displayed. Any explanation about that? The message is confusing cause it seems to have failed, but it should be running still...

This is because of the socket read timeout, you can read [more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

By default, the read times out in 30s while the re-indexing is still in progress. You can increase the timeout to avoid this error.

Also, even if it times out, you can use below [command to check current progress](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api)

```
GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex
```

Comment: This really answers the final question of the problem. Thanks.