# Facing error while rollover based on alias and template in elasticsearch 5.6.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am facing a strange problem while rollover of a particular alias.
Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "index name [twitter] does not match pattern '^.*-\\d+$'"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "index name [twitter] does not match pattern '^.*-\\d+$'"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I have a template as below:

```
{
     "template": "twitter-*",
     "settings": {
       "number_of_shards": 3
     },
     "mappings" : {
           "user" : {
             "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "text" },
                    "id" : { "type" : "text" }
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

And alias list

```
 GET /_aliases
```

> ```
> {
>   "twitter": {
>     "aliases": {}
>   },
>   ".kibana": {
>     "aliases": {}
>   },
>   "twitter-2019.06.09-1": {
>     "aliases": {
>       "twitter-alias": {}
>     }
>   },
>   "twitter123": {
>     "aliases": {}
>   }
> }
> ```

I have created twitter-2019.06.09-1 from twitter index by takng snapshot and restore process.

Whenever I try following rollover manually(I was setting it up by curator), I face above error.

```
#Running manual rollover
POST /twitter-alias/_rollover/
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age":   "7d",
    "max_docs":  1
  }
}
```

twitter-2019.06.09-1 has following 3 records:

```
GET twitter-2019.06.09-1/user/_search?size=0
{
  "took": 44,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [ ]
  }
}
```

I have tried deleting the twitter index because it is of no use but same error happening by rollover api.

Please help.

Update:

After reading below post: 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rollover-failing/153676/5

I updated the template and index alias list as below:

```
#Creating template for new index creation
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "template": "twitter-*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3
  },
"mappings" : {
        "user" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "text" },
                "id" : { "type" : "text" }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases":
    {
    "search-all":{}
    }
}
```

And Index:

```
GET twitter-2019.06.09-1
{
  "twitter-2019.06.09-1": {
    "aliases": {
      "search-all": {},
      "twitter-alias": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1559904447882",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "DnUZcHiyQIi2ab8XVKKVuA",
        "version": {
          "created": "5060099"
        },
        "provided_name": "twitter"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Issue still exit.

I noticed

> "provided_name": "twitter"

while checking index info.

Is it related to the above error posted? It should not be twitter. Is it a bug?

My renaming index stretegy was:

```
#Taking snapshot
PUT /_snapshot/eaa-backup/twitter_snapshot
{
  "indices": "twitter",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```

And Restore:

```
#Now restore with new name
POST /_snapshot/eaa-backup/twitter_snapshot/_restore
{
 "indices": "twitter",
 "ignore_unavailable": "true",
 "include_global_state": false,
 "rename_pattern": "twitter",
 "rename_replacement": "twitter-2019.06.09-1"
 }
```

Please help to find out the cause of above error. Also, I have posted same issue in elastic discussions but it seems it will taking days to find help there. So , posting here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from @untergeek's reply. Below was the cause of the problem:

Actually, I tried today morning and found out the same @untergeek mentioned after doing everything fresh. It seems somehow while renaming index by taking snapshot and restore (ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626803/how-to-rename-an-index-in-a-cluster)), that

```
"provided_name": "twitter"
```

property (description in the question asked) was wrongly set and that is why I was facing problem. It should be set to

```
twitter-2019.06.09-1
```

Problem is not with the index name but the above property.

My scenario includes renaming the index and then rolling over.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/facing-error-while-rollover-based-on-alias-and-template-in-5-6-0/184869/3), but include the answer I provided there for reference.

Rollover indices must end in a dash and a number, typically (you have to go through hoops with the rollover API calls to get around this). Curator was checking for the index associated with your rollover alias (which is `twitter` in the pasted block), which does not end with a dash and a number.

I'm not quite sure what you're doing wrong. Here's a working example:

```
PUT twitter-2019.06.09-1
{
  "aliases": {
    "twitter-alias": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}

PUT twitter-alias/_doc/1
{
  "doc1": "dummy_doc1"
}
PUT twitter-alias/_doc/2
{
  "doc2": "dummy_doc2"
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "old_index" : "twitter-2019.06.09-1",
  "new_index" : "twitter-2019.06.09-000002",
  "rolled_over" : true,
  "dry_run" : false,
  "conditions" : {
    "[max_docs: 1]" : true
  }
}
```

Additionally:

```
GET twitter-alias
```

Yields:

```
{
  "twitter-2019.06.09-000002" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "twitter-alias" : {
        "is_write_index" : true
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {...},
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1560216263049",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "kMd6jt_dSWKSCW4ertSuLg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7010099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "twitter-2019.06.09-000002"
      }
    }
  },
  "twitter-2019.06.09-1" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "twitter-alias" : {
        "is_write_index" : false
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {...},
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1560216199250",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "zjIKove5SXqAXSEfseYpQg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7010099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "twitter-2019.06.09-1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```