# elasticsearch aggregations truncates decimals

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

This is the query I made using Kibana:

```
GET sensor-data/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "devId.keyword": {
              "value": "a8404143e1877ae1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-06-28T11:21:00.447Z",
              "lte": "2023-06-28T11:22:19.447Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "max": {
      "max": {
        "field": "data.EnergyMeterV1.u1.v"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response I get from elasticsearch:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 5.491925,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sensor-data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c0C8AYkBNIM9Q_24x62m",
        "_score" : 5.491925,
        "_source" : {
          "$sRef" : "DeviceMetricV1",
          "devId" : "a8404143e1877ae1",
          "timestamp" : "2023-06-28T11:21:31.390Z",
          "data" : {
            "EnergyMeterV1" : {
              "$sRef" : "EnergyMeterV1",
              "u1" : {
                "v" : 234.897,
                "u" : "V"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "max" : {
      "value" : 234.0
    }
  }
}
```

Notice in hits section that for the query I made, for a very short time interval, there is only one document with value 234.897.

Question: How can I make aggregations to include the value as it is and not truncated from 234.897 to 234.0?

Comment: Can you check your index mapping for the field `data.EnergyMeterV1.u1.v`, it might well be that it's been mapped as `integer` or `long`

Comment: @Val it has ```"type" : "long"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get is probably due to the fact that your `data.EnergyMeterV1.u1.v` field is of type `integer` or `long`. Even though your source document contains a double, only the integer part has been indexed and the aggregation can only aggregate what's been indexed, i.e. the integer part.

You have two options to fix this:

A. You create a new index with the correct mapping (i.e. `double` or `float` type) for the `data.EnergyMeterV1.u1.v` field and reindex your data from your old index into this new one.

B. You add another `double` or `float` field into your current index mapping and then you can update-by-query your index and copy the `data.EnergyMeterV1.u1.v` field value into the new field you've added.

Depending on the amount of data you have, you might prefer one option over the other, A being the cleanest.

Comment: also there is a need for few more steps to have the index with the same name but with the updated mappings. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59397746/2281611